# How to make a chat app like Facebook?

Tags: android, json

I'm working on a chat app. I want to create a cool design for my listview. My code is working but I want to add some design similar to the design of Facebook, but I have a problem.

I can't do this: i.e one user has an ID=52 and the other has=5293. If the user has Id=52, the textarea gravity in the left and the other in the right, and here my code it doesn't see my if statement every time print the else statement I don't know why really I put my ID in an array but really this is the same result.

```
   public void LoadMessage() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatabseHandler d = new DatabseHandler(EchangingMessage.this);
            String me = d.getData();

            TextView you_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.you_id);

        String you = you_id.getText().toString().trim();

        Log.i("ID  :", me + " : " + you);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("me", me));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("you", you));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_daftar_rs, "POST",
                params);

        try {

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            Log.i("success :", "" + success);

            if (success == 1) {

                daftar_rs = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DAFTAR_RS);
                for (int i = 0; i < daftar_rs.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = daftar_rs.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id_rs = c.getString(TAG_ID_RS);
                    String nama_rs = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_RS);
                    String link_image_rs = "http://10.0.2.2/www/Android_Login_Secure/Images/upload/big/"
                            + c.getString(TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS);


                    String message_rs = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE_RS);
                    String time_rs = c.getString(TAG_TIME_RS);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID_RS, id_rs);
                    map.put(TAG_NAMA_RS, nama_rs);
                    map.put(TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS, link_image_rs);
                    map.put(TAG_MESSAGE_RS, message_rs);
                    map.put(TAG_TIME_RS, time_rs);
                    DaftarRS.add(map);

                }
            } else {
                    finish();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "COnnection:" + e.toString());
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                // updating listview 
                SetListViewAdapter(DaftarRS);
                } 
            });
    }


public class ListAdapterSendMessage extends BaseAdapter {

public String POST_TEXT;
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
public final static String you_id = null;

int count = 0;

public ListAdapterSendMessage(Activity a,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_send, null);
    }

    HashMap<String, String> daftar_rs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    daftar_rs = data.get(position);

    String me = daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS);

    if (me == "52") {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_even, null);

        TextView name_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.senderMessage);

        TextView Des_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.message);
        ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.imageSender);
        TextView Time_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.senderTime);

        name_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_NAMA_RS));
        // link_image_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MainActivity.TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS));
        // alamat_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MainActivity.TAG_ALAMAT_RS));
        Des_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_MESSAGE_RS));
        Time_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_TIME_RS));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(
                daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS), thumb_image);

    } else {


        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_odd, null);

        TextView name_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.senderMessage);

        TextView Des_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.message);
        ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.imageSender);
        TextView Time_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.senderTime);

        name_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_NAMA_RS));
        // link_image_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MainActivity.TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS));
        // alamat_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MainActivity.TAG_ALAMAT_RS));
        Des_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_MESSAGE_RS));
        Time_rs.setText(daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_TIME_RS));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(
                daftar_rs.get(MyMessages.TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS), thumb_image);

    }

    return vi;

}
}
```

Comment: And the reason this is tagged PHP?

Comment: yeah you're right because am working with localhost yet sorry

Comment: If is definitely a statement, not a function.

Comment: come on I made a mistake don't complain me this is problem lost my mind  and I don't know why people like to destroy other people 
at least say some hopeful word :(

Comment: Ignore ManOfSnow.  Mark was making a constructive point, but like you say, the 2nd guy is just being an ass.

Comment: ok you tell me what should I do what should I say

Comment: Hi @Shanaz. I've asked a mod to remove the comment from Man Of Snow - in general, just ignore unhelpful remarks. There's always one or two on beginner questions! In this question, I suspect it's not getting much in the way of answers because it's not entirely clear what the problem is. It features code you've tried, which is great, now all we need to do is help Android coders understand the issue. One way to do this is to draw a screenshot of what you have, and one of what you want. If you keep them reasonably small (640x480 is good), upload them into the question - they should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this question we assume that my id =1 and you id =2

```
if (id==1) {
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_right, parent, false);

else
{
      inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_left, parent, false);
}
```

here you have to different layout one of them item_list_right and the other one is item_list_left 
I solved this problem like this